# How do I set the output file's version in JScript.NET using JSC?

Tags: version-control, version, versioning, jscript

I'm using jsc.exe (I don't have Visual Studio) to compile a JScript.Net script into a DLL, and I want to be able to set the version info. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I already checked the possible arguments during compilation, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545446/how-do-i-set-assembly-attributes-version-etc-in-jscript-net