# How do I set assembly attributes (version, etc) in JScript.NET?

Tags: metadata, .net-assembly, jscript.net

I have some javascript that I'm compiling with Microsoft's jsc.exe compiler into a .NET assembly. I would like to set some assembly metadata, such as the file version, but it is unclear to me how to do that.

How can I set these assembly-level attributes in JScript.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyCompanyAttribute("Your Company")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyrightAttribute("Copyright Your Company 2014")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescriptionAttribute("Description")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersionAttribute("1.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyProductAttribute("Blah blah")]
[assembly: AssemblyTitleAttribute("Title")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademarkAttribute("Trademark Your Company 2014")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.0")]
```